# How do I calculate two separate means for a vector with both characters and numbers?

Tags: r

New to R.. I created a BMI variable and pasted it with the sex variable so I can see which BMI is labeled  M (male) or F (female). How do I find the mean of group M and group F separately?

I've tried using the substr and gsub functions to get rid of the characters but am not sure that's the solution because then I have no way of knowing whether the BMI value should be calculated as M or F.

edit:

I want to calculate the means for M and F separately to learn how to do simple subgroup analyses. I've been trying to learn R independently, and this particular BMI problem is from an old problem set.

edit:

I see why pasting doesn't work here. I was treating the `paste` function like `proc format` in SAS.

```
set.seed(123)
sex <- sample(x = c("M", "F"), size = 100, replace = TRUE)
height.cm <- rnorm(n = 100, mean = ifelse(sex == "M", 175, 163), sd = 3)
weight.kg <- -110 + height.cm * 1.1 + rnorm(n = 100, sd = 7)
waist.in <- -20 + ifelse(sex == "M", 35, 33) + 0.5 * weight.kg + rnorm(n = 100, sd = 2.5)

bmi <- weight.kg / (height.cm / 100) ^ 2

bmi_sex <- paste(sex, bmi, sep = "")
```

Comment: Do not paste atomic values together. Use a data frame which is actually a `list` of equal length atomic vectors, here being *sex* and *bmi*. This allows you to run *any* analysis on indicator and numeric data.

Comment: I created the data frame by doing `df <- data.frame(bmi, sex)`. How do I then calculate the means for M and F?

Comment: Much better. Also, this post feels like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377). Can you ask the real *x* question and not ask help with your proposed *y* solution?  Specifically, why do you need to *find the mean of group M and group F separately*? You can easily answer your question in one object: `aggregate(bmi ~ sex, mydataframe, FUN= mean)`. Please edit question with fuller background of problem.

Comment: @Parfait Updated. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the mean based on `bmi` and `sex` variable

```
tapply(bmi, sex, mean)

#       F        M 
#25.81020 27.14678
```

There is no need of `bmi_sex` variable to calculate this but if this is how we get the input we can use some regex to separate sex and the actual bmi value

```
tapply(as.numeric(sub(".(.*)", "\\1", bmi_sex)), sub("(.).*", "\\1", bmi_sex), mean)

#       F        M 
#25.81020 27.14678
```

---

We can write a function to get bmi value for one sex at a time.

```
get_bmi <- function(bmi, sex, select_sex) {
   mean(bmi[sex == select_sex], na.rm = TRUE)
}
```

and then call it by

```
get_bmi(bmi, sex, "F")
#[1] 25.8102
get_bmi(bmi, sex, "M")
#[1] 27.14678
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to calculate the M and F means separately instead of having them together in the output?

Comment: @user12310746 What do you mean by separately? If you store this into a variable `output <- tapply(bmi, sex, mean)`, `output[1]` will give you mean for "female" and `output[2]` for "male".

Comment: Separately as in whether there's a way I can specify within the function that I want only the mean bmi for females?